# Start Task Instance Error

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I created a simple workflow in Informatica 9.6.x. So while validating the workflow, it get's validated. But at the time of deploying the application, I am getting the following error - 
End task instance[End_Event] is not connected to any other object.

Similar error, I am getting for Start task as well

[image]

Comment: That's odd. Can you try saving the workflow before deploying it?

Comment: Yeah, that turned out to be the reason. I am a beginner, sorry for that and Thanks Marek